# Canvas Drawing Unwanted Partial Border on Text in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I'm not sure if this is a partial border or a shadow, but there is something going wrong with `fillText`.

I've made a [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8h6edysa/) where I simply fill some white text.

This is what the outcome looks like in Chrome version: 59.0.3071.86

[image]

I actually had to take a screen shot to show what was wrong.

When I save the image, there is nothing weird surrounding the text.

This must just be the way Chrome is displaying it.

Firefox displays it just fine:

[image]

So, is there anything that I can do to make Chrome stop displaying the text this way?

This is making the labels in my charts look terrible!

I'm using white in my example because it really highlights the error, but this appears to happen with any color that I fill the text with.

Is there a canvas context setting I can use to fix this, or is this a Chrome bug?

Comment: Link to fiddle?

Comment: @Colin Oops, forgot that. Thanks. I added it to my question. Here it is too : https://jsfiddle.net/8h6edysa/

Comment: With this same Chrome build 59.0.3071.86 and on 58 before I upgraded I wasn't seeing anything like that (macOS Sierra)

Comment: @ColinD Hmm... Ok. I'll check some other platforms. Thanks for checking.

Comment: if I try windows with same chrome I was seeing the glitch, but then if I added a width and a height to the canvas, it went awayl e.g. <canvas id="canv" width=400 height=200></canvas>